# Still getting error connect ECONNREFUSED using node.js MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im still getting error: ECONNREFUSED myip+port, I have tried to add port but it doesnt help.
Do you know what could help please?

here is my code,

```
//importing mysql and csvtojson packages 
const csvtojson = require('csvtojson'); 
const mysql = require("mysql"); 
  
//database definition
const hostname = "127.0.0.1", 
    username = "root", 
    password = "root", 
    databsename = "csvtomysql",
    port = "8889"
  
//connection to the database 
let con = mysql.createConnection({ 
    host: hostname, 
    user: username, 
    password: password, 
    database: databsename, 
    port: port,
}); 
  
con.connect((err) => { 
    if (err) return console.error( 
            'error: ' + err.message); 
  
    con.query("DROP TABLE sample",  
        (err, drop) => { 
  
        // Query to create table "data" 
        var createStatament =  
        "CREATE TABLE data(Favorites char(10), " + 
        "From URL char(1000),To URL char(1000),Anchor Text char(2000),Link Status char(400), Type char(500), BLdom float, DomPop float, Power int, Trust int, Power*Trust float, Alexa float, IP char(100), CNTRY char(5))"
  
        // Creating table "data" 
        con.query(createStatament, (err, drop) => { 
            if (err) 
                console.log("ERROR: ", err); 
        }); 
    }); 
}); 
  
// CSV file name 
const fileName = "testData.csv"; 
  
csvtojson().fromFile(fileName).then(source => { 
  
    // Fetching the data from each row  
    // and inserting to the table "sample" 
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) { 
        var Favorites = source[i]["Favorites"], 
            FromUrl = source[i]["From URL"], 
            ToUrl = source[i]["To URL"], 
            AnchorText = source[i]["Anchor Text"],
            LinkStatus = source[i]["Link Status"], 
            Type = source[i]["Type"], 
            BLdom = source[i]["BLdom"], 
            DomPop = source[i]["DomPop"], 
            Power = source[i]["Power"], 
            Trust = source[i]["Trust"], 
            PowerTrust = source[i]["Power*Trust"], 
            Alexa = source[i]["Alexa"], 
            Ip = source[i]["IP"], 
            Cntry = source[i]["CNTRY"]
  
        var insertStatement =  
        `INSERT INTO sample values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`; 
        var items = [Favorites, FromUrl, ToUrl, AnchorText, LinkStatus, Type, BLdom, DomPop, Power, Trust, PowerTrust, Alexa, Ip, Cntry]; 
  
        // Inserting data of current row 
        // into database 
        con.query(insertStatement, items,  
            (err, results, fields) => { 
            if (err) { 
                console.log( 
    "Unable to insert item at row ", i + 1); 
                return console.log(err); 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
    console.log( 
"All items stored into database successfully"); 
});
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Why are you using port 8889? The default port for MySQL is 3306. Did you start the MySQL Server after setting a custom port? Is The MySQL Server running? Can you telnet to that port on the command-line and do you get a connection?

Comment: Are you getting your MySQL and NodeJs ports muddled up?

Comment: I saw one question and changing port to 8889 helped, I have tried 3306 port but I got same problem
but I think my problem is that my MySQL server is not running, do I have to start it somehow? I thought I can just start it with this code on localhost, am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECONNREFUSED is an error due to some misconfiguration (as the name suggests)
Are you sure that mysql server is running on the same host of the node.js backend?
Mysql server is up and running (try to connect with a client like DBeaver on Mysql Workbench)?
The standard port for mysql is 3306 (not 8889)
If you are not sure that you have a local mysql but you have docker installed you can try it out typing

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=csvtomysql -p 8889:3306 -d mysql
```

and your application should work fine

Comment: if I try to run that command it says: 'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command